# Android back button rendering issue

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I have an issue with the backbutton rendered by wix-react-native-navigation. It has an extra bump at the left of the arrow. Anyone who knows how to fix this?

[image: Back arrow android]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue will not be fixed in version v1 of WIX: react-native-navigation.

V2 uses the native icons so this won't be a problem anymore